# Shopify - populate test store with orders

Tags: shopify

I'm building a shopify app that uses a shops order information. In order to test it properly, I need a test shop with lots of orders in it (1000+).

Is there an easy way to populate a test store with 1000+ orders?

To my knowledge, there is no API for this, and the orders need to be entered by hand. I hope there is a way to populate this

Comment: Why do the orders *need* to be in the shop? Couldn't you just mock the responses so that it appears like there are thousands of orders? There is no way to programmatically generate this many orders and I find it unlikely that you would need there to really be this many in the shop. You can get very far with mocks.

Comment: mocking is good, and its gotten me to this point, but I'd like to test against the real deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no provision for creating orders artificially for testing, through the API or otherwise.

To test against large numbers of orders you can either mock them out or open the app to beta testers by submitting it to the [Shopify App Store](http://apps.shopify.com/categories/beta?filter=all).